# Execute content.js on button click, not page load

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Not a duplicate of [Executing Chrome extension onclick instead of page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149322/executing-chrome-extension-onclick-instead-of-page-load) because I need to execute script on a button press in popup.html, not when the user presses the icon.

This is my first chrome extension and I've got my content.js working the way it should on page load, but I only want to execute it after the user pushes a button in popup.html. I know you can specify `run_at` in manifest.json, but this doesn't work because I want it to only run when the user clicks a button (not the icon), and I'm using `pageAction` so I need the icon to be grayed out on urls which don't contain the letter 'g', hence the specification in my background.js. I think I must be missing something regarding the communication between background.js and content.js, but I'm feeling very lost so if anyone can explain what I'm missing that would be great.

Here is my *manifest.json*:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "my extension",
"description": "it doesnt work",
"version": "0.1",
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": false
 },

"permissions": [
"declarativeContent"
 ],

 "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },  

"icons" : { "16": "16.png",
          "48": "48.png",
          "128": "128.png" },

"content_scripts": [
{
  "js": ["content.js"],
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
   }
   ]
   }
```

*Background.js*:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
  {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { urlContains: 'g' },
      })
    ],
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"});
   }); ]
  }
  ]);
  });
   });
```

*Content.js*:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName(".class")) {
        var x = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
       }            }
      });
```

*popup.html*:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Turn off <span>class, "class"</span></p>
<button type="button">Turn off</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally, if your user interaction *begins* with the user clicking a `browserAction` button, then the content script should be injected with [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) **instead of** a *manifest.json* `content_script` entry. It is *very* rare where you will want to inject the *same* script using both methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will run if you are on the selected tab. You may need to change how you select that tab though. Basically this will will send a request to the tab and the tab listens for these requests. If you get the proper greeting, you can do your function.

popup.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Turn off <span>class, "class"</span></p>
    <button type="button" id="button">Turn off</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
$('#button').on('click',function()
{
   chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
   });
});
```

content.js

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName(".class")) {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }            
}
```

Also, as @Makyen had suggested, remove content scripts from your manifest so it isn't always being injected into every tab. I edited my answer as well per this suggestion.

Comment: If user interaction *begins* with the user clicking a `browserAction` button, then the content script should be injected with [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) instead of a *manifest.json* `content_script` entry. Injecting into *every single URL* is lazy programming costing your user resources. What about those of us with *hundreds* of tabs? Extra content scripts in tabs where the extension is unused is not needed. (Yeah, the OP was doing it both ways, but you chose to keep the *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry).

Comment: @Makyen You are right. I edited my answer. I am still a bit rusty on my chrome extensions.

Comment: Thanks, that is better. The code you have in *background.js* should be in a script which is loaded in the *popup.html* (e.g. *popup.js* loaded in a `<script>` tag the way *content.js* is currently). The *content.js* file should not be loaded in the *popup.html*. If you are using jQuery in the popup, you will need to load it. Currently, given the minimal amount of jQuery code you are using in the popup, you should convert it to vanilla JavaScript and not load jQuery. You will need to move the `<script>` tag to the end of the `<body>` or use a `DOMContentLoaded` listener.

Comment: my jquery is rusty, can anyone convert background.js to vanilla js?

Comment: @Nat Something like this. `document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () { });` . What is in the function will be the same.

Comment: @Nat you should brush up on your jQuery because content.js would be `$(".class").hide();`

Comment: @Loaf Thank you. i am trying to accomplish this task without jQuery